# How to get list of int from EF stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I am having to convert an API project over to .NET Core.

Previously they used:

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>("exec storedProcName");
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
context.Set<int>().FromSql("storedProcName");
```

Though this worked with my other stored procs I need a way to set what the values will be when they are not entities but just ints, but rather it has to be a class in the EF context...

How can I just get a List of ints?

Comment: the EF context does not have a ExecuteStoreQuery method

Comment: `Set<TEntity>()` means `this is an entity mapped to the database`. `int` is definitely not an entity. This is *not* the correct way to execute stored procedures

Comment: Thus the question.

Comment: I want to pull all the data from the db and tell it what that data will be on each row, whether a single int or a defined class.  I'd prefer not make them entities.

Comment: @Samir: `it doesn't seem to allow me to "Set" an int` This is a mistaken interpretation on your part. `.Set<T>()` means "a **collection** of elements of type T" (set is a noun); rather than "**set** the value (where set is a verb). `Set<Foo>()` is intended to retrieve the "Foos" table which contains  elements of type `Foo`.

Comment: I have reworded it, does anyone know how to get a list of ints?

Comment: Change `int` to `int[]` or `IEnumerable<int>`...?

Comment: Why don't you just add your stored procedure to your context? In this case you will get a strongly typed method. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Look workaround here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1862